# made up an URL in wordpress and it return 404 not found

Tags: wordpress, url, server, localhost, custom-error-pages

I change the URL of my website in Wordpress to a domain that I invented and now I can't access the original URL. It return 404 not found. I know I made a big mistake, is there anyway that I can change the current URL (the one I made up) to the original URL (which is localhost/wordpress)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it in the database, in the (wp)_options table, change the value of the two first rows 'siteurl' and 'home'

Or you can set them inside you wp-config file :

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', ‘http://example.com' );
```